# operator '<<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'int'

Tags: c#

Here is part of my code

```
ushort code = ...;
...
code <<= 1;
code |=  (NextBit(ref isEndOfScan) << 0); //ERROR
```

`bool NextBit(ref bool isEndOfScan)` returning bool

I am rewriting my code from c++ to c#.
I've tried to convert function result to int or write `false` instead of `0`, but nothing helped.
I want to set 0 bit of variable `code`.

Comment: NextBit return value should be int

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C++ allows some conversions that C# doesn't - particularly around Boolean values.

In this case, you can just use the conditional operator to treat the return value as 1 or 0:

```
code |= NextBit(ref isEndOfScan) ? 1 : 0;
```